# Docker Tooling for Eclipse - how to connect to docker daemon running inside VM

Tags: eclipse, docker, virtual-machine

I have a docker daemon/engine running inside `guest` (Ubuntu) virtual machine
and as per [Docker Tooling for Eclipse](http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-03-30-Eclipse_Docker_Tooling.html) instruction I had downloaded and setup the plugin in Eclipse Mars on my `host` Mac OS machine. 
How do I connect to Docker running in guest VM from the host machine IDE.

As per instructions, I would need to enter TCP and authentication so how do I get these details to setup the connection?

I had tried with guest OS IP (i.e. `tcp://127.0.0.1:2376` output of ifconfig command with local host IP) but was not able to connect.

Comment: How did you set up the Docker VM? I'd recommend using Docker Machine to create the VM and then using `docker-machine env <machine_name>` to get the `tcp://` URI.

Comment: I just had a normal VM with ubuntu as OS and then inside VM on ubuntu OS installed the docker.

Comment: That is fine. What is the IP of the VM? 127.0.0.1 is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps I used to get Docker Tooling working in Eclipse Neon on Windows.

1. Open the `Docker Quickstart Terminal`
2. Execute `docker-machine ls`
3. Copy the URL (e.g. `tcp://192.168.99.100:2376`)
4. Click the `Add Connection` button in the toolbar for `Docker Explorer`
5. Provide a `Connection name:`
6. Select `TCP Connection`
7. Paste the above URL into the `URI:` edit box
8. Change `tcp` to `https` in the edit box
9. Select `Enable authentication`
10. Set the path to `C:\Users\`*username*`\.docker\machine\certs`
11. Click on `Test Connection` to verify

Comment: Nice procedure.  However I still get "PING FAILED" (to ucp node).  Python Docker client works just fine from windows with the same environment variables to secured ucp node.   I tried setting environment variables before starting Eclipse,  it found the created a connection but still a ping failed.   I suppose the spotify Java docker client could be tested independently next.    It would sure help if I could get Eclipse to tell me anything about the error,  even a stack trace,  some info would be nice.  Docker tooling to unsecured 2375 works fine and dandy.   Using prebuilt JBoss Dev Studio.

Comment: Root cause is that by default the unix socket through which the docker daemon communicates is not readable and writable by arbitrary users. It also prevents ordinary users from managing docker from the command line, without sudo. The accepted answer for https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo describes a way to get your user into a group which does have r/w access to that socket. After that, eclipse's docker tooling will also be able to access the local docker daemon.

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to this. First, enabling the TCP socket (which I'll answer). Then, setting TLS authentication on the socket (which I'll link to but won't cover). The first part should get you up.

You'll need to edit the `DOCKER_OPTS` settings in `/etc/default/docker` in the VM. Edit this file and set `DOCKER_OPTS` to something like:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix://"
```

Then, restart Docker (`sudo service docker restart`). This should get you a TCP connection that you can put in your Eclipse settings as:

```
tcp://10.0.2.15:2376
```

The second part (which is optional at this point) would be setting up the CA and certificates per https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/https/. But I'd actually recommend just installing Docker Machine and provisioning your VM that way as it will create the needed certificates for you. Then, if your machine was named `dev`, you just point the authentication dir to `~/.docker/machine/machines/dev`.

Comment: I had followed the step mentioned in part # 1 but getting error as ping failed while testing from eclipse

Comment: What is the error? Any logs that might say the underlying Docker error?

Comment: I could see only "ping failed" message on eclipse while connecting to docker daemon.

Comment: I had also to "sudo systemctl stop firewalld" , only then the ping succeeded

Answer (score 0):

If Docker Daemon is running(i.e docker desktop running) in window task bar , not inside the VM , just get the URI from its context menu setting. In eclipse docker tooling perspective , we can connect to running docker daemon only by providing the URI.