# Can not connect to Docker daemon from eclipse windows

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-toolbox, pkix

I can not connect to Docker daemon from Eclipse in Windows OS. I installed docker tooling plugin in my Eclipse

Here are my configurations

[image]

This is the error I am getting

[image]

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Tooling for Eclipse - how to connect to docker daemon running inside VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844845/docker-tooling-for-eclipse-how-to-connect-to-docker-daemon-running-inside-vm)

Comment: (That question suggests a different “Enable authentication; Path” than you’ve shown in your screen shot.)